# How to make my thinkpad e14 gen3 fingerprint work on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: password, lenovo, thinkpad, 22.04, fingerprint-reader

I can't see fingerprint settings on ubuntu but my ThinkPad e14 gen 3 has a fingerprint sensor. I tried some solutions found on the internet, but still no result.